Find $f \in \mathbb{Q}[S_3]$ s.t. $f^2=f$ and $f \neq 0,1$
$S_3=\{e,(1 2),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$
$\mathbb{Q}[S_3]=\{f\colon S_3\to \mathbb{Q}\}$ is a ring with pointwise addition and the following multiplication:
\begin{align*}
(f\cdot g)(x)=\sum_{y \in S_3}f(y)\cdot g(y^{-1}x)
\end{align*}
Find $f \in \mathbb{Q}[S_3]$ s.t. $f^2=f$ and $f \neq 0,1$.
I'm sure that $f(e)\neq 1$. But now there are a lot of options to define the function for the other values. I tried a lot of different ways but I can't figure it out.
Is there a method to find such an $f$, or do you have to somehow guess it?

$\mathbb{Q}[S_3] \simeq M_2(\mathbb{Q})\times \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$  - see here.

$\frac12e+\frac12(12)$

what do you mean by that Thomas?

In your notation Thomas's example is the function that takes the value $1/2$ at $e$ and $(12)$, and $0$ elsewhere. That way of writing:
$$f=\sum_{x\in G}f(x) x$$ functions as formal sums over the group is also commonly used when writing elements of a group algebra. Observe that you can replace $(12)$ with any other 2-cycle. The set of central idempotents of a group algebra are particularly important in [tag:representation-theory]. Those are stable under conjugation by a group element.

thank you, now i get it
